# Remove values from a tensor that are within a given range

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to be able to know the rounded accuracy of my neural network when the prediction is above or below a certain threshold. For example, I want it to only calculate accuracy when the prediction is above 0.55 or below 0.45 in order to filter out near 50/50 cases.

I tried using the soft_acc function on stackoverflow and adding an if else to the beginning to filter out the near 50/50s.

```
def soft_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    if y_pred > 0.55 or y_pred < 0.45:
        return K.mean(K.equal(K.round(y_true), K.round(y_pred)))
```

I received the following error message.

TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

Comment: What do you want to do when `y_pred` is between `[0.45, 0.55]`?

Comment: I would prefer for it to simply not do anything to the soft_acc metric value. @bluesummers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`tf.boolean_mask`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) to filter out values at indices that don't meet the required threshold.

```
# remove values from `X` in interval (lo, hi)
mask = tf.math.logical_or(tf.lesser(X, lo), tf.greater(X, hi))
X = tf.boolean_mask(X, mask)
```

In your case, you would define `soft_acc` as

```
def soft_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = tf.math.logical_or(tf.greater(y_pred, 0.55), tf.lesser(y_pred, 0.45))
    y_true2 = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, mask)
    y_pred2 = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask)

    return K.mean(K.equal(K.round(y_true2), K.round(y_pred2)))
```